# jQuery UI modal is not returning true and false

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want it to check it in if condition. How do I use it?

```
function notification_dialog_box(title,html,icon)
{
    var text = '<p><span class="'+icon+'" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 50px 0;"></span>'+ html  +'</p>';
    var $myDialog = $('<div id="dialog-message"></div>').html(text).dialog({
        modal: true, zIndex: 10000, autoOpen:true,width: 'auto', modal: true, resizable: false,title: title,
        buttons: {
            "OK":function(){$(this).dialog("close"); return true;}, 
            "Cancel":function() {$(this).dialog("close");return false;}
            }
        });
}

if(notification_dialog_box('Out of designer\'s', 'All Designer\'s are assigned in this project', 'ui-icon ui-icon-info' ))
{
code....
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are returning true/false in an **asyc callback.**

**ie**: the code that returns true/false does not run until user clicks a button, but your code has already finished running.

you need to switch to a callback structure for your code to work.

**ie**: you need to pass a function to `notification_dialog_box` that gets called when user click a button and gets passed the value of what they clicked.

something like this:

```
function notification_dialog_box(title,html,icon, fn)
{
    var text = '<p><span class="'+icon+'" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 50px 0;"></span>'+ html  +'</p>';
    var $myDialog = $('<div id="dialog-message"></div>').html(text).dialog({
        modal: true, zIndex: 10000, autoOpen:true,width: 'auto', modal: true, resizable: false,title: title,
        buttons: {
            "OK":function(){$(this).dialog("close"); fn(true);}, 
            "Cancel":function() {$(this).dialog("close"); fn(false);}
            }
        });
}

notification_dialog_box('title', 'blah blah blah', 'ui-icon ui-icon-info', function(ok){
  if(ok) {
     //code
  } 
} )
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a jQuery Model box as the JavaScript `Confirm()` i.e. the javascript does not wait for the user response

The right approach is to use callback functions.

```
function notification_dialog_box(title, html, icon, success, failure) {
    var text = '<p><span class="' + icon + '" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 50px 0;"></span>' + html + '</p>';
    var $myDialog = $('<div id="dialog-message"></div>').html(text).dialog({
        modal: true,
        zIndex: 10000,
        autoOpen: true,
        width: 'auto',
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        title: title,
        buttons: {
            "OK": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                success()
            },
            "Cancel": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                failure()
            }
        }
    });
}

if (notification_dialog_box('Out of designer\'s', 'All Designer\'s are assigned in this project', 'ui-icon ui-icon-info', function() {
    // success code here
}, function() {
    // error code here
}) ​
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

As @mkoryak said you cant return like that from an async callback. Instead you can do something like

```
function notification_dialog_box(title,html,icon,callback)
{
    var text = '<p><span class="'+icon+'" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 50px 0;"></span>'+ html  +'</p>';
    var $myDialog = $('<div id="dialog-message"></div>').html(text).dialog({
        modal: true, zIndex: 10000, autoOpen:true,width: 'auto', modal: true, resizable: false,title: title,
        buttons: {
            "OK":function(){$(this).dialog("close"); callback(true);}, 
            "Cancel":function() {$(this).dialog("close");callback(false);}
            }
        });
}



function dialog_callback(retVal){
    if(retVal)
      // user clicked on Ok
    else
      // clicked on Cancel
}

notification_dialog_box('Out of designer\'s', 
     'All Designer\'s are assigned in this project', 
     'ui-icon ui-icon-info', 
      dialog_callback // pass the callback
);
```